# firebase - get all chat rooms for a member

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm integrating multi-room chat in my app and I'm stuck with getting a list of all chat room a specific user is member of.

The structure looks like this:

[image: members structure]

The rooms and members are created with *childByAutoId* like this:

```
FIRUser *user = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser;  
mdata[@"uid"] = user.uid;

roomKey = [[_rootRef child:@"messages"] childByAutoId].key;

NSString *memberID = [[[_rootRef child:@"members"] child: roomKey ] child: user.uid ].key;

// set Meta data for member to be able to recognize later

[[[[_rootRef child:@"members"] child: roomKey ] child: memberID ] setValue:mdata];
```

Now I'm trying the get the list of rooms for a (hard coded) user like that:

```
-(void) getRoomKeys {

    [[[[_rootRef child: @"members"] queryOrderedByChild:@"uid" ] queryEqualToValue:@"QLfRoGpoCjWpzira7fljBj8g3EJ3"]
     observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
         NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *message = snapshot.value;
     }];
  }
```

This return 0 key/value pairs.

When I take out the query I get all room keys. When I change the structure to this
[image: uid one level higher]

I will get all rooms for that user but with this structure I can't add other members to that room. So I need to dig one level deeper.

So how to set the query for nodes that have been created by childByAutoId?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Frank, I just noticed that you edited something, but could not spot your edits. Could you indicate? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try considering this data structure.

```
{
    "rooms": {
        "-KQgDxLIt88yPt6nacDu": { ... }
    },
    "members": {
        "QLfRoGpoCjWpzira7fljBj8g3EJ3": { ... }
    },
    "member-rooms": {
        "QLfRoGpoCjWpzira7fljBj8g3EJ3": {
            "-KQgDxLIt88yPt6nacDu": true
        }
    }
}
```

You can retrieve the keys of the rooms a member is part of by observing `member-rooms/{uid}`:

```
[[_rootRef child: @"member-rooms/QLfRoGpoCjWpzira7fljBj8g3EJ3"] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
     NSLog("%@", snapshot.value); // the keys of the rooms of the member
}];
```

Comment: Callam, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I followed your suggestion and it works well, so I upvoted. Nevertheless this is not actually the answer to my question "how to set the query for nodes that have been created by childByAutoId?", so I hesitate to accept this as answer.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Get a list of rooms a member is in? or get the members of a particular room?

Comment: I would like to get a list of all rooms a member is in. That's what your approach does, but you are changing the structure of the database to achieve this. I'm afraid to run into that again when further developing the app with changing requirements and loose backward compatibility by that. So I wonder why 'queryEqualToValue:' doesn't look into all childs but stops at the first child.